# Using PHP/Google Maps to Calculate Distances

Tags: php, maps

I'm trying to create a simple (or so I thought) PHP/Google Maps function which would allow me to calculate a distance between two addresses. I'm new to PHP, and here's what I've got so far, however, something's wrong.

```
<section class="group">

        <label for="start">Start:</label>
        <input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="" />

        <label for="finish">Finish</label>
        <input type="text" name="finish" id="finish" value="" />

        <input type="button" value="Calculate distance" id="calculate-distance" />

        <div id="results"></div>

    </section>

    <?php
    function getLatLong($address) {

    $address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $geoloc = curl_exec($ch);

    $json = json_decode($geoloc);
    return array($json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat,
    $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);

    }

    function Haversine($start, $finish) { 

    $theta = $start[1] - $finish[1];
    $distance = (sin(deg2rad($start[0])) * sin(deg2rad($finish[0]))) + (cos(deg2rad($start[0])) * cos(deg2rad($finish[0])) * cos(deg2rad($theta)));
    $distance = acos($distance);
    $distance = rad2deg($distance);
    $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;

    return round($distance, 2);
     }

    $start = getLatLong('start');
    $finish = getLatLong('finish');

    $distance = Haversine($start, $finish);

    print('<p>The distance between ['.$start[0].', '.$start[1].'] and   ['.$finish[0].',    '.$finish[1].'] is '.$distance.' miles ('.($distance * 1.609344).'  km).</p>');
?>
```

Comment: Enlighten us ... what is the error you receive?

Comment: Hey, 

What happens is that it doesn't react to anything when I press "Calculate Distance" - instead it already publishes a distance before I even get to insert any addresses (3722.70235392 km) and I've no idea where that comes from.

Comment: Possible solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041227/distance-from-point-a-to-b-using-google-maps-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$from = "erode";
$to = "Chennai";

$from = urlencode($from);
$to = urlencode($to);

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);

$time = 0;
$distance = 0;

foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $time += $road->duration->value;
    $distance += $road->distance->value;
}
$km=$distance/1000;
echo "To: ".$data->destination_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "From: ".$data->origin_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "Time: ".$time." seconds";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Distance: ".$distance." meters";
echo "<br/>";
echo $km;
?>
```

Comment: Yep! works like a charm. Had to change http to https and add api key

Comment: @IwanRoss - where did you add API keys? Where to get one? Can you pls share the updated code?

Answer (score 2):

just copy and paste run and have fun.........

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--
 Copyright 2008 Google Inc. 
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0: 
 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAjU0EJWnWPMv7oQ-jjS7dYxSPW5CJgpdgO_s4yyMovOaVh_KvvhSfpvagV18eOyDWu7VytS6Bi1CWxw" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var pano;
var svClient;
var directions;
var route;
var vertices;
var vertexMap;
var stepToVertex;
var stepMap;
var currentLatLng;
var panoMetaData;
var close = false;
var bearing;
var nextBearing;
var nextVertexId;
var nextVertex;
var progressArray;
var progressDistance;
var currentStep;
var carMarker;


 var selectedStep = null;
 var driving = false;
 var advanceTimer = null;
 var advanceDelay = 1;
 function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var start = new GLatLng(37.090240,-95.712891);
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(start, 3);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());

    carMarker = getCarMarker(start);
    map.addOverlay(carMarker);
    carMarker.hide();

    svClient = new GStreetviewClient();
    pano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetview"));

    GEvent.addListener(pano, "initialized", function(loc) {
      panoMetaData = loc;
      moveCar();
    });

    GEvent.addListener(pano, "error", function(errorCode) {
      showStatus("The requested panorama could not be displayed");
    });

    directions = new GDirections(map);
    GEvent.addListener(directions, "load", function() {
      jumpInMyCar();
    });

    GEvent.addListener(directions, "error", function() {
      showStatus("Could not generate a route for the current start and end addresses");
    });
  }
}

function getCarMarker(start) {
  return new GMarker(start, getArrowIcon(0.0));
}
function setCarMarkerImage(bearing) {
  carMarker.setImage(getArrowUrl(bearing));
}
function generateRoute() {
  var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
  var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
  directions.load("from: " + from + " to: " + to, { preserveViewport: true, getSteps: true });
}

function jumpInMyCar() {
  route = directions.getRoute(0);
  collapseVertices(directions.getPolyline());
  map.setCenter(vertices[0], 16);
  renderTextDirections();
  checkCoverage(0);
}
function checkCoverage(step) {
  if (step > route.getNumSteps()) {
    hideStatus();
    stopDriving();
    jumpToVertex(0);
  } else {
    if (step == route.getNumSteps()) {
      ll = route.getEndLatLng();
    } else {
      ll = route.getStep(step).getLatLng();
    }

    svClient.getNearestPanorama(ll, function(svData) {
      if (svData.code == 500) {

        setTimeout("checkCoverage(" + step + ")", 1000);
      } else if (svData.code == 600) {

        showStatus("Street View coverage is not available for this route");
      } else {

        checkCoverage(step + 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
function jumpToVertex(idx) {
  currentLatLng = vertices[idx];
  nextVertex = vertices[idx + 1];
  nextVertexId = idx + 1;

      bearing = getBearingFromVertex(idx);
  nextBearing = getBearingFromVertex(idx + 1);

  setCarMarkerImage(bearing);
  carMarker.setLatLng(currentLatLng);
  carMarker.show();

  currentStep = stepMap[idx];
  constructProgressArray(idx);
  setProgressDistance();
  updateProgressBar(0);

  map.panTo(currentLatLng, 16);
  highlightStep(currentStep);
  checkDistanceFromNextVertex();

  pano.setLocationAndPOV(currentLatLng, { yaw:bearing, pitch:0 });
  svClient.getNearestPanorama(currentLatLng, function(loc) {
    if (loc.code == 500) {
      setTimeout("jumpToVertex(" + idx + ")", 1000);
    } else if (loc.code == 600) {
      jumpToVertex(nextVertexId);
    } else {
      panoMetaData = loc.location;
      panoMetaData.pov.yaw = bearing;
      moveCar();
    }
  });
}
function moveCar() {
  currentLatLng = panoMetaData.latlng;
  carMarker.setLatLng(currentLatLng);
  map.panTo(currentLatLng);
  svClient.getNearestPanorama(panoMetaData.latlng, function(svData) {
    if (svData.code == 500) {

      setTimeout("moveCar()", 1000);
    } else if (svData.code == 600) {

      jumpToVertex(nextVertexId);
    } else {
      panoMetaData.links = svData.links;
      checkDistanceFromNextVertex();
      if (driving) {
        advanceTimer = setTimeout("advance()", advanceDelay * 1000);
      }
    }
  });
}
function checkDistanceFromNextVertex() {
  close = false;
  var d = currentLatLng.distanceFrom(nextVertex);
  var b = getBearing(currentLatLng, nextVertex);
  if (getYawDelta(bearing, b) > 90) {
    incrementVertex();
    if (driving) {
      checkDistanceFromNextVertex();
    }

  } else {
    updateProgressBar(progressDistance - d);
    if (driving) {
      updateViewerDirections(progressDistance - d);
    }
    if (d < 10) {
      close = true;
    }
  }
}


function advance() {

  var selected = selectLink(bearing);
  if (close && nextBearing) {
    var selectedTurn = selectLink(nextBearing);
    if (selectedTurn.delta < 15) {
      selected = selectedTurn;
      incrementVertex();
    }
  }

  if (selected.delta > 40) {
    jumpToVertex(nextVertexId);
  } else {
    var panAngle = getYawDelta(panoMetaData.pov.yaw, panoMetaData.links[selected.idx].yaw);
    pano.panTo({ yaw:panoMetaData.links[selected.idx].yaw, pitch:0 });
    setTimeout(function() {
      pano.followLink(panoMetaData.links[selected.idx].yaw);
    }, panAngle * 10);
  }
}
function selectLink(yaw) {
  var Selected = new Object();

  for (var i = 0; i < panoMetaData.links.length; i++) {
    var d = getYawDelta(yaw, panoMetaData.links[i].yaw);
    if (Selected.delta == null || d < Selected.delta) {
      Selected.idx = i;
      Selected.delta = d;
    }
  }
  return Selected;
}
function incrementVertex() {
  if (! vertices[nextVertexId + 1]) {
    endReached();
  } else {
    nextVertexId++;
    nextVertex = vertices[nextVertexId];
        bearing = getBearingFromVertex(nextVertexId - 1);
    nextBearing = getBearingFromVertex(nextVertexId);
    setCarMarkerImage(bearing);
    if (stepMap[nextVertexId - 1] == currentStep) {
      progressArray.push(nextVertex);
    } else {
      currentStep = stepMap[nextVertexId - 1];
      highlightStep(currentStep);
      progressArray = [ currentLatLng, nextVertex ];
      updateProgressBar(0);
    }

    setProgressDistance();
  }
}
function endReached() {
  stopDriving();
  updateProgressBar(0);
  showInstruction("You have reached your destination");
  document.getElementById("step" + selectedStep).style.backgroundColor = "white";
  selectedStep = null;
}
function getBearingFromVertex(n) {
  var origin = vertices[n];
  var destination = vertices[n+1];
  if (destination != undefined) {
    return getBearing(origin, destination);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
function updateViewerDirections(distanceFromStartOfStep) {
  var lengthOfStep = route.getStep(currentStep).getDistance().meters;
  var distanceFromEndOfStep = (lengthOfStep - distanceFromStartOfStep);
  distanceFromEndOfStep *= 3.2808399;

  var uiDistance, unit;
  if (distanceFromEndOfStep > 7920) {
    distanceFromEndOfStep /= 5280;
    uiDistance = distanceFromEndOfStep.toFixed(0);
    unit = 'miles';
  } else if (distanceFromEndOfStep > 4620) {
    uiDistance = '1';
    unit = 'mile';
  } else if (distanceFromEndOfStep > 3300) {
    uiDistance = '&frac34;';
    unit = 'mile';
  } else if (distanceFromEndOfStep > 1980) {
    uiDistance = '&frac12;';
    unit = 'mile';
  } else if (distanceFromEndOfStep >  660) {
    uiDistance = '&frac14;';
    unit = 'mile';
  } else {
    uiDistance = (Math.round(distanceFromEndOfStep / 10)) * 10;
    unit = "ft";
  }

  if (route.getStep(currentStep + 1) != undefined) {
    showInstruction('In ' + uiDistance + ' ' + unit + ': ' + route.getStep(currentStep + 1).getDescriptionHtml());
  } else {
    showInstruction('In ' + uiDistance + ' ' + unit + ': You will reach your destination');
  }
}
function constructProgressArray(vertexId) {
  progressArray = new Array();
  var stepStart = stepToVertex[currentStep];
  for (var i = stepToVertex[currentStep]; i <= vertexId + 1; i++) {
    progressArray.push(vertices[i]);
  }
}
function setProgressDistance() {
  var polyline = new GPolyline(progressArray);
  progressDistance = polyline.getLength();
}
function updateProgressBar(progress) {
  progress = (progress < 0 ? 0 : progress);
  var stepLength = route.getStep(currentStep).getDistance().meters;
  setProgressBarLength(1 - (progress / stepLength));
}
function setProgressBarLength(progress) {
  var width = (636 * progress);
  if (width < 0) {
    width = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = width + "px";
}
function getYawDelta(a, b) {
  var d = Math.abs(sanitiseYaw(a) - sanitiseYaw(b));
  if (d > 180) {
    d = 360 - d;
  }
  return d;
}
function sanitiseYaw(yaw) {
  if (yaw > 360 || yaw < 360) {
    yaw = yaw % 360;
  }
  return yaw;
}
  function getArrowIcon(bearing) {
  var icon = new GIcon();
  icon.image = getArrowUrl(bearing);
  icon.iconSize = new GSize(24, 24);
  icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(12, 12);
  return icon;
}



function getArrowUrl(bearing) {
  var id = (3 * Math.round(bearing / 3)) % 120;
  return "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_" + id + ".png";
}

   function collapseVertices(path) {
 vertices = new Array();
 vertexMap = new Array(path.getVertexCount());

 vertices.push(path.getVertex(0));
 vertexMap[0] = 0;
 for (var i = 1; i < path.getVertexCount(); i++) {
   if (! path.getVertex(i).equals(vertices[vertices.length - 1])) {
     vertices.push(path.getVertex(i));
   }
   vertexMap[i] = vertices.length - 1;
 }

 stepToVertex = new Array(route.getNumSteps());
 stepMap      = new Array(vertices.length);

 for (var i = 0; i < route.getNumSteps(); i++) {
   stepToVertex[i] = vertexMap[route.getStep(i).getPolylineIndex()];
 }

 var step = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
   if (stepToVertex[step + 1] == i) {
     step++;
   }
   stepMap[i] = step;
 }
}

 function renderTextDirections() {
  var startAddress = route.getStartGeocode().address;
  var   endAddress = route.getEndGeocode().address;
  var html  =  getDirectionsWaypointHtml(startAddress, "A");
      html +=  getDivHtml("summary", "", route.getSummaryHtml());
  for (var n = 0; n < route.getNumSteps(); n++) {
    html += '<a onclick="selectStep(' + n + ')">';
    html += getDivHtml("step" + n, "dstep", route.getStep(n).getDescriptionHtml());
    html += '</a>';
  }
  html += getDirectionsWaypointHtml(endAddress, "B");
  document.getElementById("directions").innerHTML = html;
  setWaypointIcon('A');
  setWaypointIcon('B');
}
function getDirectionsWaypointHtml(address, letter) {
 var content = getDivHtml('letter' + letter, 'letterIcon', "");
     content += '<span class="waypointAddress">' + address + '</span>';
  return getDivHtml("wayPoint" + letter, "waypoint", content);
}
function setWaypointIcon(letter) {
  var png = 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/icon_green' + letter + '.png';
  document.getElementById('letter' + letter).style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + png + ')';
}
function getDivHtml(id, cssClass, content) {
  var div = "<div";
  if (id != "") {
    div += ' id="' + id + '"';
  }

  if (cssClass != "") {
    div += ' class="' + cssClass + '"';
  }

  div += '>' + content + '</div>';
  return div;
}
function selectStep(i) {
  var vertex = vertexMap[route.getStep(i).getPolylineIndex()];
  stopDriving();
  jumpToVertex(vertex);
}
function highlightStep(i) {
  if (selectedStep != null) {
    document.getElementById("step" + selectedStep).style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  document.getElementById("step" + i).style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeff";
  selectedStep = i;
}
function startDriving() {
  hideInstruction();
  document.getElementById("route").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("stopgo").value = "Stop";
  document.getElementById("stopgo").setAttribute('onclick', 'stopDriving()'); 
  document.getElementById("stopgo").onclick = function() { stopDriving(); }
  driving = true;
  advance();
}
function stopDriving() {
  driving = false;

  if (advanceTimer != null) {
    clearTimeout(advanceTimer);
    advanceTimer = null;
  }

  document.getElementById("route").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("stopgo").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("stopgo").value = "Drive";
  document.getElementById("stopgo").setAttribute('onclick', 'startDriving()'); 
  document.getElementById("stopgo").onclick = function() { startDriving(); }
  showInstruction('Press <b>Drive</b> to follow your route');
}
function setSpeed() {
  advanceDelay = document.getElementById('speed').selectedIndex;
}
function showStatus(message) {
  hideInstruction();
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById("status").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("streetview").style.display = "none";
}
function hideStatus() {
  document.getElementById("status").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("streetview").style.display = "block";
}
function showInstruction(message) {
  document.getElementById("instruction").innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById("instruction").style.display = "block";
}
function hideInstruction() {
  document.getElementById("instruction").style.display = "none";
}
function getBearing(origin, destination) {
  if (origin.equals(destination)) {
    return null;
  }
  var lat1 = origin.lat().toRad();
  var lat2 = destination.lat().toRad();
  var dLon = (destination.lng()-origin.lng()).toRad();

  var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
  var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
          Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
  return Math.atan2(y, x).toBrng();
}
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
}
Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
  return this * 180 / Math.PI;
}
Number.prototype.toBrng = function() {
  return (this.toDeg()+360) % 360;
}
</script>
<style>

body {
position: relative;
}

#content {
width: 640px;
padding: 8px;
background-color: #eeeeff;
border: 1px solid #000066;
}

#svPanel {
width: 638px;
height: 319px;
position: relative; 
}

#status {
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left: 0px;
width: 638px;
text-align: center;
font: 32pt sans-serif;
color: #666666;
background-color: white; 
}

#instruction {
  position: absolute;
  top: 295px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 638px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 16pt sans-serif;
  color: #eeeeee;
  display: none;
}

#svPanel, #directions, #map {
 border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
}

#streetview {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 638px;
height: 319px;
}

#progressBorder {
position: relative;
width: 638px;
height: 10px;
margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
border: 1px solid #000066;
background-color: white;
overflow: hidden;
}

 #progressBar {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #000066;
 width: 636px;
 height: 8px;
 top: 1px;
 right:1px;
}

#map {
  width: 317px;
 height: 317px;
 margin-right: 1px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#directions {
width: 317px;
height: 400px;
margin-left: 1px;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
}

.waypoint {
position: relative;
background-color: #eeeeee;
border: 1px solid #666666;
padding: 6px;
margin: 4px;
font: 10pt sans-serif;
}

.letterIcon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 38px;
  background-image: none;
 }

.waypointAddress {
position: absolute;
top: 17px;
left: 32px;
}

#summary {
padding: 4px;
font: 10pt sans-serif;
}

.dstep {
border-top: 1px solid #666666;
padding: 4px;
padding-left: 8px;
font: 10pt sans-serif;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: white;
}

.label {
 width: 52px;
 text-align: right;
 font: 12pt sans-serif;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 4px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 }

.input {
 float: left;
 width: 252px;
 text-align: left;
 }

 .controls {
  clear: both;
  padding: 4px;
 }

#speed {
  float: left;
 }

#buttons {
 float: right;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
 }

  </style>
  </head>
<body onload="load();" onunload="GUnload();">
<div id="content">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div id="svPanel">
      <div id="streetview" style="width: 638px; height: 319px;"></div>
      <div id="status">Enter your start and end addresses and click <b>Route</b></div>
      <div id="instruction"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressBorder">
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id="map"></div>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="label">From</div>
        <div class="input"><input id="from" size="30" value=""/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="label">To</div>
        <div class="input"><input id="to" size="30" value=""/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="label">Speed</div>
        <div id="actions">
          <select id="speed" onchange="setSpeed()">
            <option value="0">Fast</option>
            <option value="1" SELECTED>Medium</option>
            <option value="2">Slow</option>
          </select>
          <div id="buttons">
            <input type="button" value="Route" id="route" onclick="generateRoute()" />
            <input type="button" value="Drive" id="stopgo"  onclick="startDriving()"  disabled />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="directions"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yea he probably wants that when he's tagging php